# Networkx - retrieve fully connected components from graph

Tags: python, graph, networkx

Is it possible to retrieve fully connected components from a graph where 'every' node within a component are connected to 'all' of the other component nodes?

I have tried the following:

```
import networkx as nx

edges = [
    ('a', 'b'),
    ('a', 'c'),
    ('b', 'c'),
    ('a', 'd'),
    ('f', 'g')
    ]

graph = nx.Graph(edges)
result = list(nx.connected_components(graph))
print(result)
```

The results are as follows:
`[{'b', 'c', 'a', 'd'}, {'f', 'g'}]`

The issue I have is that the first component includes the node label `d`, even though it does not have any edges with every other node in the first component.

The results that I would like are:
`[{'b', 'c', 'a'}, {'f', 'g'}]`

Comment: Technically, `b` also doesn't have edges to **all other nodes** in the subgraph since it doesn't connect `d`. This example is trivial but how this would generalize is unclear. What if you had a `h` connecting `d`? or `b`? Please clarify the exact logic.

Comment: Thanks @mozway: I'm exploring this approach as a pre-processing step for a different downstream task that requires items that are all connected to each other (if more than two). It's not actually a network/graph related task (I was just exploring this approach).

In terms of your questions, because `b` is not connected to `d`, but is connected to both `a` and `c` (which are connected to each other), a component with items `{'a', 'b', 'c'}` (and not `d`) is taken. If there's a `h` connected to `d`, then the final solution would be as follows:
`[{'b', 'c', 'a'}, {'f', 'g'}, {'d', 'h'}]`

Comment: What if you had a `c-d`/`c-h`/`d-h` edges? Would you want `[{a,b},{c,d,h}]` or `[{a,b,c},{d,h}]`? There's not always a unique combination. I'll provide an incomplete answer since this doesn't give you exactly what you requested but you might be able to work from there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you might want to find the [cliques](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clique_(graph_theory)), which is achieved with [`find_cliques`](https://networkx.org/documentation/stable/reference/algorithms/generated/networkx.algorithms.clique.find_cliques.html):

```
out = list(nx.find_cliques(graph))
```

Output: `[['f', 'g'], ['a', 'd'], ['a', 'b', 'c']]`

Now, you can post-process this output to form non overlapping groups. Since removing one or more items from a clique still yields a clique, you can sort by decreasing size and remove the already seen nodes:

```
seen = set()
out = []
for c in map(set, sorted(nx.find_cliques(graph), key=len, reverse=True)):
    c -= seen
    seen.update(c)
    if c:
        out.append(c)
```

Output: `[{'a', 'b', 'c'}, {'f', 'g'}, {'d'}]`

Note that this doesn't always yield the possibility with cliques of a maximum size.

For instance with:

[image]

This yields:

```
# before filtering
[['g', 'f'], ['c', 'd', 'a'], ['c', 'd', 'h'], ['c', 'b', 'a']]

# after filtering
[{'a', 'c', 'd'}, {'h'}, {'b'}, {'f', 'g'}]
```